# 127.0.0.1 with docker-compose

Tags: docker, flask, redis, docker-compose

I have a project and I have to use 127.0.0.1 to connect redis to flask but I can't seem to link it with this IP address.
Here is my docker-compose.yml, as well as my flask.

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  poll:
    container_name: poll
    build: ./poll
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=app.py
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    networks:
      - poll-tier

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - poll-tier

networks:
  poll-tier: {}
```

And my flask (I don't have the right to modify it in my project) :

```
app = Flask(__name__)


def get_redis():
    if not hasattr(g, 'redis'):
        g.redis = Redis(host="127.0.0.1", db=0, socket_timeout=5)
    return g.redis
```

If you have a solution i'm okay

Comment: Change `Redis(host="127.0.0.1"` to `Redis(host="redis"`

Comment: I would like to, but the project forbids modifying flask

Comment: Build a mono-container get the redis image and install on it python, or vice-versa (get python image and install redis on top of it)

Answer (score 0):

Each container is isolated and each treats `127.0.0.1` as loop-back address. So the only way, if you cannot change the address (however that seems strange because you build `poll` image and hence you can control how your image is being built), is to pack your Flask app and redis to a single image.

Comment: I need to do 2 `FROM image` in my Dockerfile ?

Comment: No, you do `from` one image and then use docker commands to add other required staff. Say you derive from redis and then install python, flask and all those things.